# Kindle: File transfer over WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, file-sharing, file-transfer, kindle

I can connect my Kindle via USB and transfer files between my computer and my Kindle.  How can I do the same using WiFi?  For example, from my computer is there a way to browse what's on my kindle (assuming they are on the same WiFi network)?

Ideally I could access my Kindle as a network share or over FTP, or something.

Comment: I don't think it is possible unless you want to syncs the files from amazon or using build-in browser.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you should start a Web server on your Computer and after that download files on Kindle using built-in Experimental browser.

Following is the instruction how to configure MiniWeb web server. Other people use Calibre. The idea behind is the same.

On Windows:

1. Download [MiniWeb](https://sourceforge.net/projects/miniweb/) web server
2. Extract MiniWeb server. Let's say to `path_to_miniweb`
3. Create new folder for books (i.e. `path_to_created_book_folder`) on your computer and copy your books there
4. For convenience create Shortcut on desktop:
   `"path_to_miniweb\miniweb.exe" -p 8001 -r "path_to_created_book_folder"`
5. Click on Shortcut. Console window should appear:

   `MiniWeb (built on May 12 2018)
   (C)2005-2013 Written by Stanley Huang stanleyhuangyc@gmail.com
   Host: 0.0.0.0:8001
   Web root: C:\Users\super_user\Desktop\Books
   Max clients (per IP): 32 (0)
   URL handlers: 1
   Dir listing enabled`
6. Determine your Computer's IP address. Let's suppose it is: `192.168.0.4`
7. To test if everything is done correctly on this step, open Internet Explorer (or any other browser you have) and navigate to `192.168.0.4:8001`. You should see list of books. Please note, if your Wi-Fi connection is set as Public network, Web server may not be visible for your home devices.

On Kindle:

8. Open Experimental Browser and navigate to `192.168.0.4:8001`. As a result you will see content of the `path_to_created_book_folder`.
9. Click on Book and accept file download.
10. After download complete, go to the Home screen. Your book will be there.

**Later**, every time when you need to upload book:

1. start MiniWeb server using shortcut on desktop.
2. Copy book to `path_to_created_book_folder`
3. Use Experimental Browser on your Kindle to download book

**NOTE:** that Kindle supports limited set of book formats (i.e. *.mobi, *.txt)

Comment: Calibre comes already with the server feature [built-in](https://www.epubor.com/calibre-tutorial-transfer-e-books-to-kindle-through-local-wireless-transmission.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is an FTP server application available.
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0055SCX66/ref=mas_ty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055SCX66)

The single biggest problem with it is that currently the keyboard does not appear so you cannot change the default passwords or add new users.  That makes this app VERY insecure on the Fire so you have to be careful to turn it off when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Miniweb and then realized Calibre has an amazing file host option.

[Calibre Tutorial: Transfer E-books to Kindle through Local Wireless Transmission](https://www.epubor.com/calibre-tutorial-transfer-e-books-to-kindle-through-local-wireless-transmission.html)

My kindle had to go to the mobile non-javascript version which was not only built into calibre which I already had, but the web interface is customized and easier than the basic miniweb setup.

I also have a home linux htpc/webserver but the calibre option still seems the most convenient in use.

Comment: This is a bit of a link only answer. Please [edit] and include the relevant details from the link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's pretty convenient [SendToKindle app](https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle) by Amazon allowing to upload books over WiFi using their service.

[This help page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=200767340) mentions also sending to your Kindle email address alternative.